# Visual C++ redist not detected by command line

Tags: python, windows, visual-c++, discord.py

When trying to install discord.py, I keep getting this error:

> error: Microsoft Visual C++ 14.0 or greater is required. Get it with
> "Microsoft C++ Build Tools":
> https://visualstudio.microsoft.com/visual-cpp-build-tools/

Even though I have [Visual C++](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fQwST.png), I installed the things in [build tools](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AMw6S.png), and I added [C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\BuildTools\VC](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nJdkr.png) to the Path.

Why does Visual C++ still not work?

Comment: I dont know for sure rn, but in the `VC` folder should be a folder called `bin`. Set the path to this folder instead

Answer (score 0):

I previously had this issue, to solve it you need to head to the [link provided](https://visualstudio.microsoft.com/visual-cpp-build-tools/). Afterwards, open up the file (should be called `vs_BuildTools`) that was given to you. You should see a menu appear with multiple options (see image).

The solution is to click the `Desktop development with C++` as checked and install (bottom right).

[image: Screenshot of installer]

Afterwards, make sure no errors happens and then restart your computer.
Once that's done, you should be set and the issue should be resolved.

If you've already installed this, try uninstalling and reinstalling (what I had to do since I already had it installed).

Comment: Your solution and Kejax's both don't work, and I'm sure it's not a problem of corrupted files because I just did an sfc /scannow. Do you know anything else that might've caused my problem?